# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Left side must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have no idea why this error is happening.
I'm using rails 5 from master repo.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  q = Question.new({
    ... some random attrs
  })

  q.tests.build({
    name: 'teste',
    slug: 'teste',
    year: 1990
  })
  q.save!

end
```

---

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tests, join_table: :tests_questions
end
```

---

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions, join_table: :tests_questions
end
```

---

Some part of the trace:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Left side must exist
activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:67:in `raise_validation_error'
activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `block in save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:374:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:371:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:84:in `save_through_record'
activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:47:in `insert_record'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:379:in `block in save_collection_association'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:370:in `each'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:370:in `save_collection_association'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:184:in `block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:157:in `instance_eval'
activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:157:in `block in define_non_cyclic_method'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `block in call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `each'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:305:in `_create_record'
activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:521:in `create_or_update'
activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:301:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:558:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:501:in `call'
activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:301:in `create_or_update'
activerecord/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `create_or_update'
activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:151:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `block in save!'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:374:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:371:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:303:in `save!'
```

---

When I use the `=` method, instead of `build`, active record just ignore the `join_table`, picking the table name as `questions_tests` instead of `tests_questions`.

ex.:

```
q.tests = [] of tests
```

---

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `questions_tests' for #<Question:0x0000000516b188>
```

Comment: any update on this? thanks

Comment: I just bundle updated and this error is not happening anymore, but I'm receiving an enum error now: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each_with_index' for true:TrueClass`

`rails-e18bf1dc4922/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb:159:in 'block (2 levels) in enum'`

Comment: updating did not solve for me. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21041)

Comment: @masciugo, actually, the error persists, but the enum error was masking it (yes, a new error! ¬¬)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21041).

As @pixeltrix stated:

> Hmm, looks like the one of the belongs_to associations on the
>   constructed join model isn't pointing to the right column so is seen
>   as nil. Previously this wasn't a problem but since we require
>   belongs_to associations by default now it blows up. The easy fix is
>   just to put optional: true on the :left_side association when it's
>   constructed but I think we can do better than that